# ValueError: Need 2 classes but I have 0

Tags: python, dataframe, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

I need two classes but I have just one class so I got ValueError:

For Logistic Regression to understand, I converted string data types to integer data type. While there are Abnormal and Normal string values in the Class column, I updated them to 1 and 0. When I tried to fit Logistic Regression it gave an error. It says I need at least 2 classes but I have 1 class. I can't go back to the master data because I didn't copy the data before how can i fix it ?

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
```

```
data["class"] = [1 if each == "Abnormal" else 0 for each in data ["class"]]
```

```
data.head()
```

```
lr = LogisticRegression()
lr.fit(x_train.T, y_train.T)
```

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_16508\1381464910.py in <module>
      1 #Eğitim
      2 lr = LogisticRegression()
----> 3 lr.fit(x_train.T, y_train.T)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_logistic.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
   1552         classes_ = self.classes_
   1553         if n_classes < 2:
-> 1554             raise ValueError(
   1555                 "This solver needs samples of at least 2 classes"
   1556                 " in the data, but the data contains only one"

ValueError: This solver needs samples of at least 2 classes in the data, but the data contains only one class: 0
```

I wanted to return to the original data, but I cannot return to the main data because I did not copy the master data before. I tried changing the data in the Class column to 1 and 0 but they are all corrected to 1 i.e. Abnormal.

Answer (score 0):

```
ValueError: This solver needs samples of at least 2 classes in the data, but the data contains only one class: 0
```

This error means the label column only contains one type of label.

For example, we have a dataset looks like below:

```
label | f1 | f2
1 | a1 | b1
1 | a1 | b2
...
1 | aN | bM
```

As all instances belong to 1 or 0, classification couldn't build a model for it.

Not sure why you treat a string column as label, if you couldn't get origin data, could you provide your transferred data as example? It may be helpful to check detail data example

Answer (score 0):

```
data["class"] = [1 if each == "Abnormal" else 0 for each in data["class"]]
```

I think you are trying to do a list comprehension but see you have data["class"] instead of data ["class"] without a space at opening bracket.
hope this works.

Comment: Spaces between tokens (other than indentation) are ignored in Python.